# Django, CSS is loading, however images and js return a 404

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am creating a Django website and have created a login pages for the website. When I run this on the development server the CSS for the page loads but the images and JavaScript are returning a 404 error. but they are in the same assets folder.

[image]

**Folder Structure:**

[image]

**settings.py:**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')]
```

**Login.html:**

```
<div class="h-center">
    <img class="logo" src="{% static 'assets/base/img/logo/logo.jpg' %}">
</div>
```

I don't understand why it is only loading the CSS files.

Comment: did you add {% load static %} at the top below the <!DOCTYPE html> in your template

Comment: yeah. I have that in the `head` tag of the template

Comment: did you run python manage.py collectstatic?

Comment: I did not, that seems to have works thank you

Comment: I am glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

comment the STATIC_ROOT like this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')]
```

STATIC_ROOT is for command "collectstatic"